# How to Keep Screen On in Android Tv

Tags: java, android, android-tv

I am developing two applications for android tv.

1. The first is a launcher to customize the startup interface a bit.
2. The second is a video player by HLS or Streaming by https.

They independently work great.

Then in the launcher I have an attempt that starts the video player after 1 minute.
The problem is that after 20 minutes the Smart TV enters this suspension or low-power mode.

I already tried keepOnScreen in the layout, I tried WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON without good results.

Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.abc");
startActivity(launchIntent );

Note: When I open the multimedia application of the Smart TV and return to the player, the Smart TV does not turn off.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `VideoSupportFragment` then you can access to `SurfaceView` and do this in your `onViewCreated(..)` callback to keep the screen on:

```
getSurfaceView().setKeepScreenOn(true);
```

same in Kotlin:

```
surfaceView.keepScreenOn = true
```

---

OR, in your XML layout, add this to your `View`:

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```